# In the Stripes framework, how do I dependency inject fields in my action bean when using the MockRoundtrip?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, stripes

Here's an example of setting up Stripes to use the MockRoundtrip:

```
private void setupStripes() {
    context = new MockServletContext("testresults");

    // Add the Stripes Filter
    Map<String,String> filterParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
    filterParams.put("ActionResolver.Packages", "com.test.project.action,com.test.results.action");
    context.addFilter(StripesFilter.class, "StripesFilter", filterParams);

    // Add the Stripes Dispatcher
    context.setServlet(DispatcherServlet.class, "StripesDispatcher", null);


    mockRoundtrip = new MockRoundtrip(context, MyActionBean.class);
    assertNotNull(mockRoundtrip.getActionBean(MyActionBean.class));
}
```

The problem is that last line always fails the assertion.  You have to call `mockroundtrip.execute("eventName")` first, but by that time, your action bean has already been created for you.  If your action bean does things that depend on the appserver (eg: use EJBs, do JNDI lookups) you can never complete the call of `execute()`.  What I'd like to be able to do is get my action bean instance, dependency inject its fields, and *then* call `execute()`.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on the mailing list and got this answer:

> Apparently the guy uses an Interceptor for his tests.
>
> I think that's what you want too. Write a Stripes Interceptor that performs the "injection" as you want, and only register this one for your unit tests. You don't have to stub anything IMO.
>
> Btw that's what @SpringBean does: it's based on Interception as well.

In summary, make an interceptor that you only use when you run test code.  This interceptor can Dependency Inject that action bean that you're testing.